# I want to fit 10 to 12 views in a LinearLayout with equal weight distribution

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I am learning about `TextView` and making a birthday list app. I am learning on udacity.

I adjusted the weight to 1 and height to 0dp and I thought every `TextView` would space out equally. Instead only 5 `TextView`s were able to fit, and when I tried to add more there I got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c22Sb.png).

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black">

<TextView
    android:text="(: BIRTHDAY LIST :)"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    />

<TextView
    android:text="Amruta"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#F44336"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView
    android:text="Didi"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#C6FF00"
    android:textSize="24sp"  
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Anushka"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#F8BBD0"
    android:textSize="24sp"  
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Raj"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#BA68C8"
    android:textSize="24sp"  
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#7E57C2"
    android:text="Kunal"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"  
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Uncle"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#3F51B5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    />
<TextView
    android:text="Aunty"
    android:background="#1E88E5"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<TextView
    android:text="Atul"
    android:background="#0288D1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"  />
<TextView
    android:text="Papa"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#0097A7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"  
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<TextView
    android:text="Mummy"
    android:background="#00897B"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you missing a `</LinearLayout>` tag at the end? **EDIT** Nope, it's in the screenshot but not in the question code.

Comment: I'd argue this kind of layout is better suited to a `RecyclerView` as well.

Answer (score 3):

First time posting so sorry if formatting is wrong, but I fixed the problem.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black">

<TextView
    android:text="(: BIRTHDAY LIST :)"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    />

<TextView
    android:text="Amruta"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#F44336"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView
    android:text="Didi"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#C6FF00"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Anushka"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#F8BBD0"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Raj"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#BA68C8"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#7E57C2"
    android:text="Kunal"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Uncle"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#3F51B5"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    />
<TextView
    android:text="Aunty"
    android:background="#1E88E5"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<TextView
    android:text="Atul"
    android:background="#0288D1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"  />
<TextView
    android:text="Papa"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#0097A7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<TextView
    android:text="Mummy"
    android:background="#00897B"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

The error you have is because you have duplicate attributes within your TextViews. For example, the TextView that has the text "Aunty" has two instances of the line

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Similarly, the TextView with text "Uncle" has two instances of the line

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the duplicate attribute `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in the Textview with text "Uncle". Also remove the duplicate attribute `android:layout_height="0dp"` in the Textview with text "Aunty.

See the corrected version [image: here]